# Not allowed to load local resource - Glob images

Tags: php, image, directory, glob

**EDIT:**

It works like this:

```
<?php
$dirname = "c://wamp/www/www.mysite.com/uploads/images/cat1/"; 
foreach(glob($dirname.'*') as $filename){
        echo '<img src="../uploads/images/cat1/'.basename($filename).'"/>'; 
}
?>
```

---

I have 3 images in folder cat1 (local host) and I try:

```
foreach(glob('c://wamp/www/www.mysite.com/uploads/images/cat1/*.jpg') as $image){ echo "<img src='".$image."'/>";}
```

Return in console:

```
 (index):1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///c://wamp/www/www.mysite.com/uploads/images/cat1/065.jpg
(index):1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///c://wamp/www/www.mysite.com/uploads/images/cat1/asus.jpg
(index):1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///c://wamp/www/www.mysite.com/uploads/images/cat1/asus2.jpg
```

How do I resolve the error: Not allowed to load local resource?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like this:

```
                            <?php
$dirname = "c://wamp/www/www.mysite.com/uploads/images/cat1/"; 
foreach(glob($dirname.'*') as $filename){
        echo '<img src="../uploads/images/cat1/'.basename($filename).'"/>'; 
}
?>
```